# How do I use typedef for list of list?

Tags: flutter, dart, typedef

Below is my code and using List of list here and now I want to use typedef. I am new to this concept. I am learning this and try to use in my code. Can any one help me on this.

Before  code:

```
class CustomStyledText {
  final String text;
  final String styleText;
  final bool isBold;
  final bool isNumeric;

  CustomStyledText(
    this.text, {
    this.styleText,
    this.isBold = false,
    this.isNumeric = false,
  });
}

/// Creates multi line styled widget which displays list of items with bullet
class AppMultiLineText extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<List<CustomStyledText>> items;
  final String semanticsText;

  const AppMultiLineText({@required this.items, this.semanticsText}) : assert(items != null);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final style = context.appThemeData.bodyCopyDefault.appTextStyle;
    final styleBold = context.appThemeData.bodyCopyBold.appTextStyle;
    return Padding(
      padding: context.appThemeData.multilineDisplay.padding,
      child: Column(
        children: items.map((item) => _buildRow(context, item, style, styleBold)).toList(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

using typedef:

```
typedef tList = List<List<T>> Function<T>();

/// Creates multi line styled widget which displays list of items with bullet
class AppMultiLineText extends StatelessWidget {
 // final List<List<CustomStyledText>> item;
 final tList items;
  final String semanticsText;

  const AppMultiLineText({@required this.items, this.semanticsText}) : assert(items != null);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final style = context.appThemeData.bodyCopyDefault.appTextStyle;
    final styleBold = context.appThemeData.bodyCopyBold.appTextStyle;
    return Padding(
      padding: context.appThemeData.multilineDisplay.padding,
      child: Column(
       // children: items.map((item) => _buildMultiLineTextRow(context, item, style, styleBold)).toList(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Can any one help me how to change my code with typedef.

Thanks

Comment: What are you trying? `List<CustomStyledText>` is not a list inside another list? Also the name of your typedef suggests that you have a list of ints?

Answer (score 0):

In your typedef `IntList` it is a function that returns a `List<List<T>>`
in your case must be

```dart
typedef MyList<T> = List<List<T>>;


class AppMultiLineText extends StatelessWidget {
 // final List<List<CustomStyledText>> item;
 final MyList<CustomStyledText> items;
  final String semanticsText;

  const AppMultiLineText({@required this.items, this.semanticsText}) : assert(items != null);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final style = context.appThemeData.bodyCopyDefault.appTextStyle;
    final styleBold = context.appThemeData.bodyCopyBold.appTextStyle;
    return Padding(
      padding: context.appThemeData.multilineDisplay.padding,
      child: Column(
       // children: items.map((item) => _buildMultiLineTextRow(context, item, style, styleBold)).toList(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

but you need to use `dart >= 2.13.0` because this requires the 'nonfunction-type-aliases' language feature.

In your `pubspec.yaml`

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.13.0 <3.0.0"
```

For more info check this post https://medium.com/dartlang/announcing-dart-2-13-c6d547b57067

Comment: Thanks for your response. How to get the data (change with typedef)children: items.map((item) => _buildMultiLineTextRow(context, item, style, styleBold)).toList(),

Comment: typedef is only an alias so your code for your Column widget must work